# Model XOR check into unique constraint

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, constraints

I am modeling a reactions table with columns `user_id`, `post_id`, `reaction`. I want to have entries in this row to be unique which can be easily achieved with a unique index.

`reactions` can be `like`, `dislike`, `viewed`, `applauded`

Now the problem is, I also want to model a XOR relationship for `like` and `dislike`, meaning, when there is already a row with `like` for a given pst and user, it shoudn't be possible to add another row with `dislike`.

Since there are other optional reactions I don't know to write the constraint check for this. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only want the `(user_id, post_id)` uniqueness to apply when the `reaction` is `'like'` or `'dislike'`. That's a [partial index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createindex.html):

> When the `WHERE` clause is present, a *partial index* is created. A partial index is an index that contains entries for only a portion of a table, usually a portion that is more useful for indexing than the rest of the table. [...] Another possible application is to use `WHERE` with `UNIQUE` to enforce uniqueness over a subset of a table.

You want an index like this:

```
create unique index INDEX_NAME
on TABLE_NAME (user_id, post_id)
where reaction in ('like', 'dislike')
```

where you'd supply values for `INDEX_NAME` and `TABLE_NAME` of course.